Tagging of Included Graphics
Assume we want to automatically tag an included picture, say life-of-brian.eps, with a caption, say A Monty Python movie.. According to https://latex3.github.io/tagging-project/documentation/prototype-usage-instructions.html#handling-graphics-in-the-document this can be done using either
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[artifact]{life-of-brian}
  \caption{A Monty Python movie.}
\end{figure}

or
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[alt={A Monty Python movie.}]{life-of-brian}
  \caption{A Monty Python movie.}
\end{figure}

Which of the approaches are 'best', and why would it then be that one?
P.S. I know that the caption package isn't currently tagging compatible but I assume that this is going to change in the future. :-)

well replace the graphic by a black rule and then consider if the caption is enough to figure out what is behind black rule. (Personally I doubt that an alternative text saying "A Monty Python movie" correctly describes a graphic names life-of-brian.)

@UlrikeFischer Good point. For some reason I thought that the alt text was to tell what the picture was about, but that is what the caption is for; therefore my confusion.

basically if the image is part of the narrative of the document you should tag it with alt with text that could replace rather than describe the image in screen readers. If the image is cosmetic page decoration that can be dropped from the presentation without loss of understanding, mark it as an artifact

@DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. That clarified things for me.

Basically:

If the image is part of the narrative of the document you should tag it with alt with text that could replace, rather than describe, the image in screen readers.

If the image is cosmetic page decoration that can be dropped from the presentation without loss of understanding, mark it as artifact.


